# Are Aarakocra and Kenku related?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, races, aarakocra, kenku

As far as I can read, the oldest lore on Kenku states that they are avian humanoids who lost their wings and speech when they defied their god. However, I can't help draw striking, yet vague links between their description and that of the Aarakocra leaving me to assume they were once the same race.

While I have neither found sources to confirm or deny this, I did find that the issue might be stemmed in that the Kenkus predate 5e, so I thought I'd ask here, as it has helped me in a similar situation before:

**Are Aarakocra and Kenku related?** Were Kenku once Aarakocra who had fallen from grace, or were they another race of avians all together? And if so, what kind of race were they before they lost their wings?

Comment: Are you asking about the in-universe lore of the Forgotten Realms setting specifically? Or something else? (I'm not sure whether either/both of these races exist in other settings besides FR; both races were introduced in past editions, so it seems likely that one or both of these races were originally introduced in non-FR settings.)

Comment: So all bird people must be related huh. Typical mammalian centric prejudice.

Comment: @John Not at all. For instance, the Tabaxi and Leonin are both felines in nature, but their lore clearly states that they aren't of the same origin. However, both Aarakocra and Kenku have more vague origins that aren't so clearly defined, and if you would rip the wings off of a corvidae Aarakocra as 5e describes it, you'd get a similar look to a Kenku... At the time, I was actually searching for what the Kenku were like before they had lost their wings and voices.

Comment: @V2Blast Thought I answered you back in October. No, was not looking specifically in FR, but rather was looking at Kenku lore, focusing on the last part of my question (about winged kenku), though the more I searched the more my mind made links. So I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No

It's nigh impossible to prove a negative for "designer intent", but at least as far back as AD&D 1E, there's no published indication that they're related.

The biggest giveaway that any relationship would be distant/non-existent is their morphology in their early appearances. While both of them have six "limbs" in 5E (at least according to the [aarakocra illustration on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra)), two legs, two arms, and two wings, in both 1E & 2E only kenku had that design, while aarakocra had hands on their wings, without a separate set of arms (only four "limbs"). Other differences include:

- Their diet: Aarakocra are purely carnivorous, kenku are omnivores.
- Their relationship with civilization: Aarakocra are largely "savages", too separate from civilization to even tell the difference between domesticated and wild animals; kenku blend into civilization, living as tricksters and thieves.
- Supernatural aspects: Kenku are innately magical (inborn spellcasting), while aarakocra are "natural" (aside from their group ability to summon air elementals, which seems like only a partially innate ability tied to their shamanic traditions).
- Their "real world" associations: Kenku are likely an adaptation of [Tengu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengu) from Japanese mythology, while aarakocra have no obvious connection to that mythology.

It's possible later writers thought of them similarly and their descriptions drifted closer, but originally, they were *very* different, aside from the surface similarity of both being "bird-men".

Comment: My copy of the Fiend Folio from 1981 has both Aarakocra and Kenku. The illustration for Kenku looks very similar to the 5E version, though they are not a PC race in 1E nor is all the lore about lost flight in place. Aarakocra look different in the Fiend Folio from the newer versions and have much less background than the Kenku.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin: Ah, whoops. Was checking a 2E specific "first appearance list" without realizing it, so I just grabbed my 2E Monstrous Manual. Are aarakocra four-limbed in the Fiend Folio as well? To my knowledge, the first time aarakocra appear as a PC race is 2E Dark Sun, but my experience with AD&D 1E and OD&D is limited.

Comment: the original Aarakocra illustration in the Fiend Folio is clearly four-limbed while the original Kenku illustration is clearly six-limbed. The Kenku in the Fiend Folio can *fly* as they have an aerial maneuverability class.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin: Thanks. Looks like the 1E and 2E iterations were essentially the same, so my assertion that there were no meaningful overlaps beyond "both are humanoid birds" remains true back to 1E.

Comment: It’s not always impossible to prove a negative, I’m not sure why anyone started saying that like it was universally true.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: I can't prove the designers didn't have some connection in their minds between the two at *any* stage between 1E and 5E. I suppose technically I could interrogate each and every person who contributed to every edition of D&D to figure out who worked on those monsters, and whether any of them thought they were related in some way. I suppose I could be more specific and say it's nigh impossible to prove a negative in cases like this, but the point stands; all it would take to overturn it is one writer saying "I had this whole 'kenku are aarakocra cousins' backstory" to undo it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for the detailed explanation. I noticed the differences between their habits (not limb count or associations though), but I was starting to find correlational evidence and thought it might have been an evolutionary shift due to the lost limbs.  The only lore bit I am still wondering about (if you might have it) is what kind of people were Kenku before they lost their wings?

Comment: @VictorB: Oh, huh, totally missed that Kenku lost their wings in 5E. :-) All my lore info is actually taken from prior editions (when they had wings). That said, the new lore doesn't look compatible with the old 2E lore (there's no indication of any master they were serving that would have the capability to strip the *entire* race of wings); the old Kenku were tricksters (in a fey-like mold, though they weren't themselves fey), and had no special talent for mimicry (the communicated with each other telepathically, and with sign language and pantomime when "speaking" to other species).

Comment: Some characterizing quotes from 2E: "Kenku are a secretive race that lives among the human and demihuman races without the bulk of the population ever being aware of their presence." and "Kenku may appear to be friendly, helpful, and even generous. They freely give treasure to [people], but it is rarely genuine and crumbles into dust within a day. They may offer nonverbal advice to humanoids, but this is carefully designed to mislead. It may actually lead the party into dangers and difficulties they might otherwise have avoided. ... kenku have only a 5% chance of actually helping people."

Comment: Point is, the limits on spoken communication long predate the loss of their wings (if anything, they're more effective at spoken communication now with their mimicry skills, even if it's limited to echoing the phrases of others).

Comment: @ShadowRanger that lore is quite helpful to add to 5e. 1.They are depicted much like the wereraven lore I read, though the later was actually helpful (loved to hide in their human forms and give advice they would often see as ravens) and generous (collecting shineys to give to the needy). 2. The fact that they were so deceitful also adds to the 5e lore of how they lost their wings and speech, as it said they served a god and betrayed him (and what god would not want to hide how much he was made a fool of). The mimicry was developped because of this loss of communication.

Comment: 3. The telepathy/sign language actually does explain another gap in Kenku lore of 5e being "if they can communicate only in mimicry, then how do they talk to each other in isolation?" As the god would have taken the telepathy away, but they could still talk with their hands. (Mechanically, telepathy is a language while hand gestures would be like theives can't, which is more of a skill).... Now this is just conjecture on my part, but that missing lore does fit into expressing how different the Kenku have always been from the Aarakocras. Not saying they are wereravens either, but yeah.